# Watson speech to text in Node-RED crashes Node-RED application

Tags: text-to-speech, speech-to-text, node-red, ibm-watson

I am using Node-RED and I am trying to store text to speech data in a Cloudant database. That works fine and I also can get it out in msg.payload.speech but when I feed it into Speech To Text, my whole app crashes..... with this error:

```
ERR Dropped log message: message too long (>64K without a newline)
```

so it seems that the Speech To Text node cannot handle large messages. It also seems that Text to Speech makes a very long string regardless of what you inject. One word or a whole paragraph does not make any difference.

Is there a way to get around this issue in Node-RED?

Comment: Speech to Text features were updated yesterday.  Are you using the latest API?  Have you tried to call Watson directly (bypassing node-red)?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you split the audio that you feed to the STT service into smaller chunks? Does that work? How much audio are you trying to feed?

If you give us more details about what you are trying to accomplish then we should be able to help.

Can you also explain the problem that you are experiencing with TTS, what do you mean with "Text to Speech makes a very long string regardless of what you inject"?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reaction.

What I basically want to do is, using the S2T node in Node-RED. I have put a .wav file in a Cloudant database. So when I feed this .wav file into the S2T node, the app crashes. I used several ways to get the Speech into the database; 1. via the text to speech node, 2. added manually the .wav file in the database. 
When I look in Cloudant, it is one long line of characters, so I have placed the wave-file on different lines, which did not help, then  I have split up the wave-file in smaller chucks, this did not work either probably because the wave file loses it's structure.

The next thing I tried was using a flac file, which is also supported by T2S and S2T and this is a compressed audio file (factor 10), it would be less then 64k. But I got the message that only wav files are supported. Then I looked in the code of the S2T-node and found out that only wav is supported (the Watson S2T service in Bluemix supports more audio formats).

Comment: I also have tried to push the .wav file from Cloudant to an unbound Speech to Text service in Bluemix, but that does not seem to work either. My feeling is that the speech to Text node cannot handle the .wav file coming from a database.